# Що означає чворак?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Читаю у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2) про історію села Новожуків:

> Акт 1593 року згадує, що «крестьяне Новоселок» допомагали зводити ушкоджений повінню міст на Пересипницю, а через рік інший документ сповіщає про пожежу панської конюшні дворового «**чворака**».

Цікавить саме слово ***чворак***, оскільки у цьому контексті мені незрозуміле.

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/chvorak) цього слова не видає.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Словнику лемківської говірки](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/14883/%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA) знаходимо:

> чворак
>   -рака, ч. Св.
>   Хата, що складається з чотирьох кімнат.

У [Блозі МАНДРИ](http://mandry.at.ua/blog/jakshho_vam_strinetsja_chvorak/2009-10-09-12) також знаходимо це слово у цьому ж значенні:

> Як подає польська версія Вікіпедії, Czworak - budynek o czterech mieszkaniach, z których każde posiada osobne wejście z zewnątrz. Budowany zazwyczaj dla pracowników folwarcznych w dużych gospodarstwach rolnych (Czworak (budynek)).

Також у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA) також знаходимо це слово, але в іншому значенні:

> Чво́рак (пол. czworak) — срібна монета Великого Князівства Литовського XVI століття. 
>   Чворак дорівнював 4 литовським грошам або 5 польським. Карбувався чворак Литовським монетним двором у 1565–1569 роках.

У поданому Вами реченні слово **чворак** вживається у значенні хати, що складається з чотирьох кімнат.